# get to previous page with destination d6

Tags: 6

For example i have a button which has onclick event (redirecting to a user login page). When a user clicks on that button browser redirects him to page user/login, but when he's successfully logined in - how to redirect it back to the previous page? Tried module login_destination, but didn't worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onclick event, add a destination=previous_path along with your redirection url.

ie: `yoursitename.com/user?destination=previous_path`

Comment: Yeah thanks, but does it completely reload the previous page when i come back to it?

Answer (score 0):

Server side example, using [drupal_get_destination](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/6):

```
// Login link that redirects back to current path
$login = l(t('Login'), 'user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()) ;
// debug
drupal_set_message($login);
```

and as an onclick attribute, example using an image:

```
$url = url('user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination());
$image_path = path_to_theme().'/images/login.png'; // or drupal_get_path
$login = theme('image', $img_path, t('Login'), t('Login'), array('onclick' => 'javascript:location.href='.$url)); // or jquery.onclick it
// debug
drupal_set_message($login);
```

Note, this is OTTOMH

Personally, I'd do it server side for reliability.